# R: Unbalanced panel, create dummy for unique observations

Tags: r, panel-data

I have an unbalanced panel data (meaning that some individuals are not observed at all time periods). I would like to create a dummy variable that takes the value 1 if an individual is observed at two or more of the periods and 0 if not. 
Is someone able to do that and could explain it to me? 
Sorry if the question seems a bit "trivial".

I have tried this, but it creates multiple dummies and I only need one.

```
for(level in unique(df$id)){
share[paste("dummy", level, sep = "_")] <- ifelse(df$id == level, 1, 0)
}
```

A small example could be:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 happy = sample(c("yes", "no"), 20, replace = TRUE))
```

And expected output:

```
id   happy   dummy
 3     no      1
 8     no      0
 5     no      1
 9     no      1
10     no      1
 1     no      1
 6     no      1
 9     no      1
 6    yes      1
 5    yes      1
10     no      1
 5     no      1
 7     no      0
 6     no      1
 2    yes      0
 9    yes      1
 3     no      1
 1    yes      1
 4    yes      0
10    yes      1
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you could avoid the loop and try this:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
             happy = sample(c("yes", "no"), 20, replace = TRUE))

library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(dummy = ifelse(length(id)>=2, 1, 0))

> df
# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   id [10]
      id happy dummy
   <int> <fct> <dbl>
 1     3 no        1
 2     8 no        0
 3     5 no        1
 4     9 no        1
 5    10 no        1
 6     1 no        1
 7     6 no        1
 8     9 no        1
 9     6 yes       1  
10     5 yes       1
11    10 no        1
12     5 no        1
13     7 no        0
14     6 no        1
15     2 yes       0
16     9 yes       1
17     3 no        1
18     1 yes       1
19     4 yes       0
20    10 yes       1
```

Essentially, this approach divides up `df` by unique values of `id` and then creates a column `dummy` that takes the value 1 if there are more than two occurrences of that id and 0 if not.